# Extract data from CSV files into a single excel file

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Here is the details of my question.

- I have thousands of csv files needed to be combined in a single excel file.
- Only certain data of each csv file needed to be extracted, A2, G2 and highest value of H cell.
- Every csv file extracted will be in new workbook arranged by the sequence of extraction. (csv A2->A cell, csv G2->B cell, csv H->cell)

Because I have thousands of csv files, is it possible to combined all the data by selecting all the csv files in a different folder?

Thanks so much for the attention.

```
Option Explicit

Function ImportData()

Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook   As Workbook
Dim rngSourceRange1  As Range
Dim rngSourceRange2 As Range
Dim rngSourceRange3 As Range
Dim rngDestination1  As Range
Dim rngDestination2  As Range
Dim rngDestination3 As Range
Dim intColumnCount  As Integer

Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As String
Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String

Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook

Dim SelectedItemNumber As Integer

Dim HighestValueRng As Range
Dim Highest As Double

Do

SelectedItemNumber = SelectedItemNumber + 1

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa", 1
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2002-03", "*.xls", 2
    .Filters.Add "Command Separated Values", "*.csv", 3
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show

For SelectedItemNumber = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(SelectedItemNumber)
        Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
        Set rngSourceRange1 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Set rngSourceRange2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 6)


        wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate

        Set rngDestination1 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)
        Set rngDestination2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("H"))

        For intColumnCount = 1 To rngSourceRange1.Columns.Count

            If intColumnCount = 1 Then
                rngSourceRange1.Columns(intColumnCount).Copy rngDestination1
            Else
                rngSourceRange1.Columns(intColumnCount).Copy rngDestination1.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Next

        For intColumnCount = 1 To rngSourceRange2.Columns.Count

            If intColumnCount = 1 Then
                rngSourceRange2.Columns(intColumnCount).Copy rngDestination2
            Else
                rngSourceRange2.Columns(intColumnCount).Copy rngDestination2.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Next

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

        wkbSourceBook.Close False
    End If

Next SelectedItemNumber

End With

YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox("Continue?", vbYesNo)

Loop While YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbYes


Set wkbCrntWorkBook = Nothing
Set wkbSourceBook = Nothing
Set rngSourceRange1 = Nothing
Set rngSourceRange2 = Nothing
Set rngDestination1 = Nothing
Set rngDestination2 = Nothing
intColumnCount = Empty

End Function
```

The result of max value always return zero. Why? Anyone can correct me?

Answer (score 0):

Not positive if I completely understood your requirements, but please see if this helps you.

Paste this code into a module in a new workbook, and put your CSV files into a subfolder called "CSV". The results should appear in Sheet1 of the new workbook. Note that it will only check files with a CSV file extension. If you need to change that, look at the line `If Right(file.Name, 3) = "csv"`

```
Sub ParseCSVs()
    Dim CSVPath
    Dim FS
    Dim file
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ResultsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim RowPtr As Range
    Dim CSVUsed As Range

    Set ResultsSheet = Sheet1

    'Clear the results sheet
    ResultsSheet.Cells.Delete

    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'The CSV files are stored in a "CSV" subfolder of the folder where
    'this workbook is stored.
    CSVPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CSV"

    If Not FS.FolderExists(CSVPath) Then
        MsgBox "CSV folder does not exist."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ResultsSheet.Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("CSV A2", "CSV G2", "CSV Max of H", "File")
    ResultsSheet.Range("A1").EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
    Set RowPtr = ResultsSheet.Range("A2")
    For Each file In FS.GetFolder(CSVPath).Files
        If Right(file.Name, 3) = "csv" Then 'Only look at files with .csv extension
            Set wkb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
            Set CSVUsed = wkb.Sheets(1).UsedRange

            RowPtr.Range("A1") = CSVUsed.Range("A2")
            RowPtr.Range("B1") = CSVUsed.Range("G2")
            RowPtr.Range("C1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(CSVUsed.Range("H:H"))
            RowPtr.Range("D1") = file.Name

            wkb.Close False

            Set RowPtr = RowPtr.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next

    ResultsSheet.Range("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, I am having the problem extract the highest value in columns H, the result always shows zero. This is my code, hope anyone can correct my mistake, thanks